# core customer module external database connection magento

Tags: module, customer, core, external

I have an application which is supposed to share same database with another application ...Basically the customers are supposed to share among these two applications..Example..
www.test.com wants to read the customers of www.test1.com...So my question is ....

1)Can it be done by sharing same cookies on both the applications

2)I have tried connecting the  core customer module with external db but unable to do the same....The core connection is always from the main db witten in local.xml file of the application...hOW IT CAN BE DONE

Answer (score 1):

You can try connecting with an external database in the local.xml in the following way:

```
<database identifier>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[hostname]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[username]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[database name]]></dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
 </database identifier>
```

Comment: but that ways it will connect the whole application with that databse..I just want that customer module to be connected with the external database.......Which I have tried by changing the connection in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml but no effects..It is still showing the collection from the same db as in local.xml

Comment: anyoneee....please

Comment: HAs anyone got any answer till nowwwwwww

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up your own connections via a module's xml or in the local.xml and use the connection identifiers for customer. These should look like `customer_*` and then there will be the normal, write, read and setup.

If you look into the file `Mage_Core_Model_Resource` you can see the function `getConnection` which loads the connection for each resource.

A note that this will work out of the box if your database structure is the same as Magento, if it is not the same then you will have to extend the code.